# Pointers not returning correct value in print statement

Tags: c

I can't get this code to work. when i ran the debugger, magnitude and phase are calculated correctly but when they are printed, 180 and 0 are always printed. Here's the relevant code: function call in main:

```
double *magnitude, *phase;

cal_mag_phase(z1real, z1imag, &magnitude, &phase); 
printf("magnitude and phase (in degrees) of (%.2lf + %.2lfi) are %lf and %lf\n", 
    z1real, z1imag, &magnitude, &phase);
```

calculation function:

```
void cal_mag_phase(double z1real, double z1imag, double magnitude, double *phase)
{ 
    //magnitude is square root of components squared 
    *magnitude = sqrt(pow(z1real,2)+pow(z1imag,2)); 
    //phase is calculated then converted to degrees 
    *phase = atan(z1imag/z1real)180/3.1415;
```

Comment: Please reformat your code so that it's inside a code sample section. Also, please include the actual data printed. Thanks!

Comment: `double magnitude, ...   *magnitude = sqrt(...`  and `atan(z1imag/z1real)180/3.1415` implies true code not posted.  Best to post real code that compiled.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the idea (I didn't check on the math aspect of this, and the "180/3.1415" after the atan() call is missing an operand), but I think this is your code with the pointers adjusted:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void cal_mag_phase(double z1real, double z1imag, double* magnitude, double* phase)
{
  //magnitude is square root of components squared
  *magnitude = sqrt(pow(z1real,2)+pow(z1imag,2));
  //phase is calculated then converted to degrees
  *phase = atan(z1imag/z1real);// what's this?-->180/3.1415;
}

int main(void) {
  double magnitude, phase;
  double z1real, z1imag;

  z1real = 1;
  z1imag = 1;

  cal_mag_phase(z1real, z1imag, &magnitude, &phase);
  printf("magnitude and phase (in degrees) of (%.2lf + %.2lfi) are %lf and %lf\n", z1real, z1imag, magnitude, phase);
}
```

I also added the variables and values for the complex Z1.

A note on your use of pointers, you were missing an '*' before one the parameters.

Other than that, I just reformatted your code. I know you're new here, but always try to clearly format code so that it's easier to read, and also test (in this case, including the declaration for Z1, which was needed to run the code).